# Trouble with PHP success response via ajax - jquery

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I am having a bit of trouble getting a search function working using ajax to bring up results as the user types in a name.
This is the site in question (you can click view all to see what is searchable) 
http://ra-yon.com/beta/Test_sites/HFE/admin/contact.php
The query in action
http://ra-yon.com/beta/Test_sites/HFE/include/queryc.php?query=ra-yon&clause=email

The code in question

```
<html>
    <head>

<style type="text/css">
body
{
background:black;
color:black;
width:100%;

}
#center
{
width:90%;
height:110%;
background:white;
margin:0 auto;
text-align:center;
color:black;
}
#insert{
background:navy; color:white; font-family:impact; font-size:18px;width:170px; height:170px; border-radius:50%;
margin:0 auto;
float: left; margin-left: 100px;
top:200px;
position: relative;
}
#insert:hover

{
background:white;
color:navy;
}
label
{width:150px;}
td
{
    border:solid 2px black;
    max-width: 250px;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">


function sendPHP(){

$('#table,#table2').css('display','none');
var query     = $('#searchname').attr('value');
var clause     = $('#searchclause').attr('value');
$.ajax({
    url: '../include/queryc.php?,
    type: 'POST',
  data: "query="+query+"&clause="+clause,
    dataType: 'html',
    success:
    function(data) {
        $(data).appendTo('#table');
    }
});
return false;
}



</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script></head>

<body>
   <a href="index.php"> <h4 style="float:right; color:blue; position: relative; left:-100px;" id="goback"> Go back? </h4></a>
    <div id="center">
<div id="queryform1" >
    <a href="#" onclick="$('#table2').css('display','block');">View All?</a>
    <span style="color:black;">search</span> <input type='text' onKeyUp="sendPHP();" name='searchname' id="searchname" />

<span style="color:black;">search by</span> <select name="searchclause" id="searchclause">
    <option value="name">Name</option>
    <option value="email">Email Address</option>
    <option value="subject">Subject</option>
    <option value="date">Date</option>

</select>
<a href="../include/downloadcontact.php">Download file?</a>

<div id="table2" style="display: none; margin: 0 auto; position: relative; top:40px; max-width:700px;">
    <div id="viewall">
        <?php
        include '../include/include.php';
        $sql = 'select * from contactus' ;



//print_r($sql);
$result=mysql_query($sql);

        ?>
        <table>
<tbody>
<th>Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Subject</th><th style="width:200px;">Message</th><th>Date</th>
<tr>
<?php
while ($client = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
echo "
<tr>

<td >".$client[name]."</td>
<td >".$client[email]."</td>
<td >".$client[subject]."</td>
<td >".$client[message]."</td>
<td >".$client[date]."</td>




</tr>";
} ?>
</tbody></table>
</div></div><div id="table">TestTestTest</div>


</div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Its a bit messy right now, I am planning on cleaning it up after I get it working.
Thank you all so much!

Comment: why not use JQuery autocomplete plugin?

Comment: Check the browser console, are you getting any error? is the request being sent? is the response what you expect it to be? is that missing ' on the ajax url a copy paste error or does it actually exist in your code?

Comment: the console is saying that the status is ok for the post, its just not getting the response back

Comment: See my last comment below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checked your code in Console.  Your function is failing.  You are missing a single quote here:

```
    url: '../include/queryc.php?',
```

I use Google Chrome's Console as well as the Console found in the Firbug extension for Mozilla Firefox.  They both are invaluable in helping sort out the minor issues

Comment: appreciate the help, but it didnt seem to alleviate the problem. Im downloading firebug now. Thank you

Comment: Now that you fixed that, your AJAX is functioning correctly ..  However it's returning the following `Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/content/30/9998930/html/beta/Test_sites/HFE/include/queryc.php on line 21`

Comment: You are using `POST` for your `AJAX` call.  Your `PHP` no doubt is using `$_GET[''];`  --  Change that to `$_POST[''];`

Comment: you are right i was using GET, good catch. However when i change it too $searchterm = isset($_POST['query'])? $_POST['query'] : '';
$searchclause = isset($_POST['clause'])? $_POST['clause'] : ''; i get the same error.

Comment: This is with the GET -http://ra-yon.com/beta/Test_sites/HFE/include/queryr.php?query=ra-yon&clause=email   This is with the post http://ra-yon.com/beta/Test_sites/HFE/include/queryr.php?query=ra-yon&clause=email

Comment: I am not seeing any error ..  When in Firbug, click the "plus sign" next to `POST http://ra-yon.com/beta/Test_sites/HFE/include/queryc.php`  ..  Then click on the `RESPONSE` tab  ..  You'll see when you type 'R' into the text field you don't return the error, but valid HTML.

Comment: its just not showing up on this page http://ra-yon.com/beta/Test_sites/HFE/admin/contact.php which is perplexing

Comment: instead of `$(data).appendTo('#table');` ..  comment that out and attempt to `alert('My data is: ' + data);` See if that returns anything ..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26470/discussion-between-matture-and-zak)